# Как получить токен VK при авторизации через SwiftyVK?

Tags: ios, swift

Интегрировал swiftyVK в своё приложение. Авторизация через приложение ВК проходит успешно. Как написано в документации, токен сохраняется в userDefaults по умолчанию. Я нашёл в userDefaults ключ Token. Но его значение не строковое, а примерно вида "Token", <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050633 34582476... и т.д.
Я пробовал вытащить этот ключ так:

```swift
        if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("Token") {
            var token = NSString(format: "%@", data)
            token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
                "<",
                withString: "")
            token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
                ">",
                withString: "")
            token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
            let tokenStr = String(token)
            print("String token = \(tokenStr)")
            print("-----------------------------------")
            print("NSString == \(token)")
        }
```

Но там очень длинный токен получается (больше тысячи символов). Как можно получить токен в этой библиотеке?

Comment: Вообще, насколько я знаю, токен берётся из ЛК на сайте vk.com/

Comment: @hedgehogues я когда в андроиде интегрировал, там после успешной авторизации, вызывается метод обратного вызова, где можно из объекта вытащить токен, по которому можно получить доступ к пользовательским данным, например почте. ЛК - это личный кабинет? Если да, тогда не пойму причём тут он. Принцип автризации такой - пользователь логинится и приложение вк даёт токен для доступа. Этот токен отправляется на наш сервер, сервер делает запрос в вк по токену и получает почтовый адрес и id аккаунта. Тогда сервер возвращает свой токен приложению, и пользователь авторизуется.

Comment: Странно, когда я хочу получить датку из VK, делаю так: 1. иду в мои приложения (vk.com/dev). 2. Выбираю приложение. 3. Иду в настройки приложения. 4. Беру id приложения. 5. Далее, юзер, который хочет использовать мою прилажку проходит аутентификацию и даёт мне токен: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=5490057&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.52

Comment: @hedgehogues swiftyVK берёт на себя авторизацию в вк. Я иду в настройки вк приложения, беру там app_id, и в моём ios приложении я инициализирую swiftyVK с этим app_id. А потом вызываю метод авторизации. И если у юзера стоит ВК приложение, то открывается оно и он даёт разрешение на использование почты. Если нет, то открывает веб-браузер и он там логинится и даёт разрешение. Далее вызывается метод обратного вызова в моём ios приложении, который сообщает, что юзер авторизовался. С этого момента я могу через swiftyVK посылать запросы на нужную мне инфу. Но мне не нужна эта инфа в приложении....

Comment: @hedgehogues мне нужен только токен. Чтобы я мог этот токен отправить на свой сервер. И с сервера пойдёт запрос по этому токену в вк, где сервер получит id и почту юзера, чтобы найти их в БД и на основе этого залогинить пользователя в ios приложении. Я бы мог конечно в приложении получить почту и id пользователя, но в таком случае (так как апи сервера открытый) любой может просто подставить id любого аккаунта вк и почту и отправить запрос на наш сервер и получить доступ к аккаунту пользователя. А вот токен вк никто не сможет подставить, так как он выдаётся только если авторизоваться в вк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так а зачем из UserDefaults что-то тащить? Плюс это уже deprecated.
После аторизации есть же колбэк со всеми данными, просто берите токен:

```
func vkDidAuthorizeWith(parameters: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    guard let token = parameters["access_token"] else {
        return
    }
    print(token)
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы меня спасли!